# Want to show first three divs, then make remainder toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a dashboard that has a series of panels. In each panel there are items. Sometimes there are lots of items in a panel. I want to show just the first three items in a panel, then a toggle to show/hide the remainder.

```html
<div class="dashboard">
  <div class="panel">
    <!-- these first three should always be visible -->
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <!-- these last two should be hidden -->
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <!-- this button should toggle display of the last two -->
    <span class="button toggle"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    <!-- this should be untouched because there are only three items -->
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <!-- as there are only three items in this panel, this button does not need to display -->
    <span class="button toggle"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using `:nth-child(-n+3)` in my sass to only show the first 3 items, which worked, but couldn't figure how to pair this with jquery to toggle the remaining divs on and off.

It's also worth mentioning that the toggle should only show/hide the items in its own panel, not all panels.

Comment: @SilverSurfer What don't you understand? It's pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as the DOM is built, loop through the panels first. As you iterate over each panel, loop through the items within it. When you get to the 4th item and beyond, add a class to the element that has `display:none` configured so those items are not initially shown and show the toggle button.

Then, on your button click, you just toggle the use of that class on those elements within the panel.

See comments inline:

```js
$(function(){

  // *** INITIALIZE THE ITEMS ***
  // Loop through the panels...
  $(".panel").each(function(index, pan){
    // Then through the items in each panel...
    var $items = $(".item", pan);
    $items.each(function(idx, item){
      // If the item is 4th or more, add the hide class, otherwise remove it.
      idx > 2 ? $(item).addClass("hide") : $(item).removeClass("hide");
    });
    // If there are more than 3 items, show the toggle button, otherwise hide it.
    $items.length > 3 ? $(".toggleButton", pan).removeClass("hide") : $(".toggleButton", pan).addClass("hide");
  });
  // *****************************

  // Set all toggle buttons to have a common click event handler
  $(".toggleButton").on("click", function() {
    // Call the toggle function and pass a reference to the
    // parent panel so that only the right child items will be toggled
    toggleItems(this.parentElement);
  });

  function toggleItems(panel) {
    // Toggle the use of the "hide" class on all the .hide members
    // that are in the referenced panel.
    $(".hide", panel).toggle("hide");
  }
});
```

```css
/* Anytime something needs to be hidden, just give it this class */
.hide {
    display: none;
}

/* Just for fun. Not needed for solution: */
.dashboard {
  background-color:#bb6;
  overflow:auto;
}

.panel {
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:calc(50% - 10px);
  border:1px solid grey;
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px;
  background-color:#cd7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dashboard">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="item">o item 1</div>
        <div class="item">o item 2</div>
        <div class="item">o item 3</div>
        <div class="item">o item 4</div>
        <div class="item">o item 5</div>
        <button class="toggleButton">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="item">o item 1</div>
        <div class="item">o item 2</div>
        <div class="item">o item 3</div>
        <div class="item">o item 4</div>
        <div class="item">o item 5</div>
        <button class="toggleButton">button</button>
    </div> 
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="item">o item 1</div>
        <div class="item">o item 2</div>
        <div class="item">o item 3</div>
        <button class="toggleButton">button</button>
    </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @scott-marcus - this seems to do the job perfectly. Only thing I would add is that items are not fixed in the DOM, they are brought in from a database. This means I don't know how many there will be in each panel, so cannot manually assign the 'hide' class. How could this be added dynamically, and how would the toggle button be hidden if there are only three items in a panel?

Comment: @Toby See my updated answer. In the future though, please be as explicit in your original question as possible so that we can give you accurate answers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
      // Set the number of items to show
     var nrToShow = 3;
     var children,nrChildren,nrToShowInThisPanel ;
     // get an array of the panels
    $(".dashboard .panel").each(function() {
     // loop on each panel to do the job
     nrToShowInThisPanel = nrToShow;
     // Get an array of items in the panel
     children = $(this).children(".item");
     nrChildren = children.length;
     if (nrChildren > nrToShowInThisPanel) {
      // Hide everybody
       $(children).hide();  
      // Show the first children
      for(var i = 0; i < nrToShowInThisPanel;i++){
       $(children[i]).show();
      }
        }else{
       $(this).children(".toggle").hide();
     }
    
    });
    
    $(".toggle").on("click",function(){
     // on click event :
     var nrToShowInThisPanel = nrToShow;
     // figure where we are
     var panel = $(this).parent();
     // Get an array of items in the panel
     children = $(panel).children(".item");
     nrChildren = children.length;
    
     for(var i = nrToShowInThisPanel-1; i < nrChildren;i++){
      $(children[i]).toggle();
     }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dashboard">
        <div class="panel">
      <div class="item">one</div>
      <div class="item">two</div>
      <div class="item">three</div>
      <div class="item">four</div>
      <div class="item">five</div>
      <div class="item">six</div>
      <div class="item">seven</div>
      <div class="item">height</div>
      <div class="item">nine</div>
            <button class="toggle">button</button>    
        </div>
    
        <div class="panel">
      <div class="item">one</div>
      <div class="item">two</div>
      <div class="item">three</div>
      <div class="item">four</div>
      <div class="item">five</div>
      <div class="item">six</div>
      <div class="item">seven</div>
      <div class="item">height</div>
      <div class="item">nine</div>
      <button class="toggle">button</button>    
     </div>
     
      <div class="panel">
      <div class="item">one</div>
      <div class="item">two</div>
      <button class="toggle">button</button>    
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't use the OP's DOM, has no explanations and doesn't do what the OP asks for.

Comment: And what about the OPs requirement: *"It's also worth mentioning that the toggle should only show/hide the items in its own panel, not all panels."* as well as the fact that you haven't explained anything that you are doing? See ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: First answer ever. I'll try to met requirements next time. Hope it is usefull anyway

Comment: OK. I'm not trying to be annoying, I'm just trying to help you understand how to provide quality answers here on SO. ;)

Comment: I understand : I did it better (I hope) and I think this time I met the requirements.

Comment: That's better, but when you are providing code that can be executed, do so with a "Code Snippet" (7th button from left on the answer toolbar. This allows users to run your code and see what it does.